# Ошибка unicodeDecodeError и TypeError при чтение txt файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот кусок кода, в котором появляется ошибка при запуске:

```
def logon(logons):
    result_list_logon = {}
    
    with open(logons) as file: 
        lines = file.readlines() 
        length = len(lines) 
        
        for i in range(length):
            each_line = lines[i]
            array_line = each_line.split(' ')
```

В функцию logon передаётся строкой путь к файлу, который затем открывается на чтение и построчно записывается в переменную lines.

Сначала была ошибка:

```
    File "/home/senior/home/log/script.py", line 121, in <module>
    all()
  File "/home/senior/home/log/script.py", line 102, in all
    logon_res = logon(logons)
  File "/home/senior/home/log/script.py", line 41, in logon
    lines = file.readlines()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 1381: invalid start byte
```

Чтобы ее исправить добавила в функцию, где файл открывается на чтение, вместо 'r' - 'rb'
И теперь получается следующая ошибка:

```
array_line = each_line.split(' ')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Это делается чтобы разбить в переменной каждую строку файла на слова по пробелу и дальше их перебирая и выводить их в нужные переменные

Не могу понять, как сделать чтобы он читался, вроде замкнутый круг получается

Скрипт запускается с Debian 11 Python3.10.11, а файл идут с Windows, думала может проблема в разных файловых системах, но файл корректно открывается в debian через nano/vim

Comment: Покажите весь текст ошибки. Замена ``r`` на ``rb`` ошибку декодирования исправить не может.

Comment: @Эникейщик изменила текст ошибки

Comment: а в какой кодировке файл и какой символ на позиции 1381?

Comment: @Эникейщик Сам файл в кодировке ansi , если указываю encoding='ascii', ошибка:

 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 1381: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: ну так какой там символ то?

Comment: Честно не нашла способа посмотреть какой это символ, вы не знаете как?

Comment: открыть файл в текстовом редакторе и посмотреть

Comment: Все решилось, по итогу в логах, которые и передаются в файле, было русское слово, так как файл в кодировке ASCI, то оно отображалось символами, поэтому проблема в исходном файле
Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: @Эникейщик ну в каких-то случаях обработка текстовых файлов как бинарных имеет смысл (когда заранее не известна кодировка, например). Если нет декодирования, то и ошибок декодирования не будет. Только тогда и при разбиении `.split(b' ')` нужно использовать вместо  `.split(' ')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался еще проще
Нужно было при открытие файла указать, чтобы если символ не подходит под кодировку его либо пропускало/либо заменяло знаками "???"

Работающий вариант:

```
def logon(logons):
    result_list_logon = {}
    
    with open(logons, encoding='ascii', errors='ignore') as file: 
        lines = file.readlines() 
        length = len(lines) 
        
        for i in range(length):
            each_line = lines[i]
            array_line = each_line.split(' ')
```

Comment: "его либо пропускало/либо заменяло знаками "???"" - ну это так себе вариант, подходит только для случаев когда это не важная информация.

Comment: В моем случае это файл логов, и оно выводило строку, но заменяло конкретно эту переменную(имя пк) на имя хоста куда подключался пользователь. А так как была остальная информация(айпи, хост, логин) это не критично для этого
А вообще думала сделать обработчик исключений, который в случае появления этой ошибки декодирует в нужный формат именно эту строку из файла и все код продолжается

Comment: По идее должно работать как вы хотели через чтение в бинарном режиме, только для split тогда аргумент тоже должен быть байтовой строкой (`b' '`). Возможно так будет проще обрабатывать.

Comment: Тоже попробовала, но все равно оно не читала кодировку сбитую даже если конкретно добавила что еще раз строку декодировать в нужную, пошла более радикальным путем игнора ошибки)))